# Delete a file with Node within a Jest test

Tags: node.js, jestjs, winston

After each test where winston logger is printing into a logfile some msg, i need to delete the file. However, nothing happens at `fs.unlinkSync(logFile);` where logFile is the path to the logfile. It is not throwing any error nor deleting the file. Winston output gets printed properly in the logfile. The path to logfile provided to fs.unlinkSync is correct as well.

````
import { getLogger, createWinstonTransports } from '../logger'; 
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import winston from 'winston';

describe('getLogger', () => {
    const logFile = path.join(__dirname,'logfile.log');
    const loggers = winston.createLogger({
        transports: createWinstonTransports(logFile),
        exitOnError: false,
    });    
    const logger = getLogger('Jest test', loggers);
    
    afterEach(() => {
        // Delete the log file after each test
        if (fs.existsSync(logFile)) {
            try {
                fs.unlinkSync(logFile);
            } catch (err) {
                console.error('Error deleting the log file: ', err );
            }
        } else {
            console.log('The file does not exist')
        }
    }, 5000)
    it('should return a logger', () => {
        logger.info('This is an info message');
    });
});```
````

Comment: What’s being tested where the log file itself matters? Are you sure you’re testing the right thing?

Comment: I want to test the output of the winston logger (not implemented in the code above) and so get it from the logfile but i don't want to keep the logfile, it is only needed for testing purpose

Comment: Mock/spy on the logger.